# Parsing XML document by Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I have an XML document where there are many tags lite this (in tag :

```
<marker city="City" address="street" coords="52.386912449620866, 16.983248591423035" desc="tel. 061 874 96 69<br><br>Poniedziałek-piątek 9:00-20:00<br>Sobota 9:00-20:00<br>Niedziela 10:00-17:00" photo="" wa_firstname="861" open="1"/>
```

And I want to parse it by Nokogiri.

First step:

```
dom = Nokogiri::XML(page, nil, "UTF-8")
```

Second:

```
items = dom.xpath("//markers//marker")
```

And my result for each `marker` is:

```
<marker city="City" address="street" coords="52.386912449620866, 16.983248591423035" desc="tel. 061 874 96 69"/>
```

But I want to have:

```
<marker city="City" address="street" coords="52.386912449620866, 16.983248591423035" desc="tel. 061 874 96 69<br><br>Poniedziałek-piątek 9:00-20:00<br>Sobota 9:00-20:00<br>Niedziela 10:00-17:00" photo="" wa_firstname="861" open="1"/>
```

Why does it cut `desc` attribute? I need this one.

I use it for other XML document and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not well-formed XML: you can't put tags inside of an attribute value. You'll need to escape the tags like this:

```
<marker city="City" address="street" coords="52.386912449620866, 16.983248591423035" desc="tel. 061 874 96 69&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Poniedziałek-piątek 9:00-20:00&lt;br&gt;Sobota 9:00-20:00&lt;br&gt;Niedziela 10:00-17:00" photo="" wa_firstname="861" open="1"/>
```

There are a number of XML validators you can use to check your file, including online ones such as http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp and command-line tools such as [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html).